# Activity -> Reputation summary shows days with zero reputation change

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-history

I noticed that in my personal `Activity -> reputation` tab I have the list of reputation changes by day. As I understand it correctly - the system should show only those days, where I have at least 1 reputation change. But as you can see in the attached pic - in 14 Aug I've no reputation change but still I can see this day in the list. Notice that I cannot see other days with 0 reputation change (for example Aug 10, Aug 19 etc.). Is it a bug or some cool feature?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no *net* reputation change. This means you had something like this happen:

- You suggested an edit to a question
- Your edit gets approved: +2 reputation
- The question gets deleted: -2 reputation

You have events that affected your reputation but the end result is that the number stayed the same.

There's a little checkbox at the bottom of the page that says *"show removed posts"*. If you check it, it will show deleted questions in your reputation changes.

Per animuson, it's also possible to have this happen because a vote/unvote or accept/unaccept on one of your posts. It's not possible to see which post this occurred on if it happens on the same day.

Comment: I see. Tried to mark that checkbox - but still getting the text "There were no net reputation changes on this day".

Comment: @BSMP That will only show things if there are actually deletion events to show. But there's still the case that when an upvote and unupvote occur the same day, we collapse and hide them completely. There's no way to ever see those.